# Add Dimensional to C++ Array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to dynamically add a dimension to an array or vector in C++?  How would one generally approach this problem?  Also, is there an STL container that would allow one to instantiate an array with N-dimensions (say if I had a class that had a member that contains multi-dimensional data, but I do not know the number of dimensions until class instantiation).  Maybe something like:

```
vector<int> ndim_vector = {20 10 50};
some_container<double> c( ndim_vector );
```

Comment: The short answer is "no", you can't do that. I have a hard time understanding how you would USE this in your program, when the code doesn't know how many dimensions the container content is.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a single dimensional vector and resize it to the total number of elements?

Comment: You could also look how [boost implements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) N-dimensional arrays

Comment: You could definitely write a container that does it. [2][3] would allocate 6, and treat indexing appropriately. If you changed it to [2][3][4] you would reallocate to 24 and have to reorganize the old elements into new positions in the array.

Comment: @Dave but then the code that uses the array has to know the dimensionality. So there is no need for dynamic dimensionality.

Comment: The boost example is great, and I may just end up using boost in the end but before I created a dependency on such a huge library I would like to check my options.  I could also use a single dimensional vector and create my own "Array" class that does all the book-keeping.  I was just curious if there was a standard way to handle the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a class that can do stuff like that. For example the [OpenCV library](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) provides N-dimensional matrices. However, there is no such thing in the STL. You can build you own classes which could implement this behavior from STL containers though. The Boost library project also provides an [multidimensional array library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not include that container. But includes `<valarray>` header file with its associated classes and template classes. `valarray` template class is unidimensional, but using `gslice` is not hard to simulate the multidimensional behavior. Adding dynamically will requires a bit more of works.

Anyway, all of this feature would be required to be encapsulated into a your own class... Or use one of the alternatives suggested by Ralh Tandetzky.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with valarray being new to C++, but it sounds very close to what I am looking for.  Thanks for the information.